Parrallel Bayesian Search SVRs seem to be dying, both in terms of CPU usage and progress
this question is not about why SVMs take long times to train, it's about inconsistent runtime with skopts BayesSearchCV and as it seems dieing processes.
Quick wrapup:
I am trying a bunch of models. RForest, KNNRegressor, LassoRegression and also SVR. Each model is trained several times for different timeframes of a timeseries, and also for different timeseries. They're trained using a custom-written RollingWindowSplit and BayesianSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning. (When saying training I really mean running the BayesianSearchCV from now on)
The different timeseries consist of the same type of features, are scaled and preprocessed the same way, and have the same dimension of labels. The samples are in the same order of magnitute, and all timeseries are trained roughly the same amount of times, either 9 SVRs or 12 SVRs are trained.
Depending on the size of the train-set, there are between 4 * 5 * 10 fits (200) with the shape of [2832,22] and 8 * 5 * 10 (400) fits with the shape of [2064,22]. This is the same for all models.
Since I want the results to be reproducable, the BayesianSearchCVs
random state is set to 42. The CV also does 5 combinations in parallel (n_points), and is allowed to use all available cores/threats (n_jobs) of my CPUs.
The problem:
When training the SVRs, as expected they take way longer than e.g. LassoRegression. However, the time is inconsistent. For one timeseries, the SVRs each takes around 2 hours to train. Another one needs 8 hours. For the two others, not one is done after 24h.
When observing the process information of my taskmanager, the python processes seem to lose subprocesses after a while, and also the total CPU consumption per process drops heavily from up to 60% to 6% (not always, not for all tho). They also seem to get stuck at the same iteration of the BayesianSearchCVs when I restart them.
To show the difference: One of the timeseries is done training all the 12 SVRs, while 2 others are stuck at the 2nd SVR, and the last one is working on the 3rd SVR. This is reproducable.
I don't have any problems with the other models. This is starting piss me of, since I can't figure out what the problem is. I was considering it's just taking long, or there are some minor but high-impact differences in the time series, but I can not believe there is such a big effect on runtime when the amound of rows and the scale of the features is the same for each.
It really seems that after a while the training just dies down and sklearn/skopt fails to report it correctly (I'd love to hear a different explanation)
What I tried to fix so far:

Running the timeseries training not in parallel.
Using a different random state
Using no random state
Running it on a different machine (with way weaker hardware tho, so it was hard to compare)
Restart my PC
Restart my PC a lot
Restart VS Code
Restart Jupyter Kernels

Additional information:
The training takes place in 4 parallel running Jupyter Notebooks started in VS Code in a local venv. My CPU is an AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D. Running on Windows 11.
P.S.: I know some code would probably nice to have to answer this. If it's absolutely needed, I will provide some, however as I wrote some util methods capsuling different parts of the object creation and starting of training away, posting a minimal runnable example would be far of the actual code, and the actual code would be a lot.
